# Parametrization by loc/scale or mean/std?

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, standardization

I need a clarification on are there any differences in parametrizing probability distributions by location and scale vs. mean and standard deviation.
For example, Python's SciPy does standardization by location and scale, but if I am to write my own distribution I can choose any of the parametrizations above, and I would like to know
are there any differences and reasons for choosing one of the two?
(S and L being location and scale and $\sigma$ and $\mu$ standard deviation and mean)

Example:
to do a gamma distribution

$f_Γ (x,a) =(x^{(a-1)} e^{(-x)})/Γ(a)$

I can use

$1/S \cdot f_Γ ((x-L)/S,a)$

or

$\sqrt{a}/σ \cdot f_Γ (a+\sqrt{a}  (x-μ)/σ,a)$

Comment: Location and scale are non-intuitive (for me, and at the risk of upsetting scipy devs, which I have done before) and hence I think this is a big downside to using scipy.  The location and the scale are not exchangeable to the mean and standard deviation, except in a handful of distributions.  More troubling, changing the loc/scale can change the bounds of a bounded distribution like the beta or binomial which results in ore mental bookkeeping in my opinion.  My own opinion would be to stick with mean/sd for these reasons.

Comment: I was not aware of the issues with bounded distributions. Thank you for that info. I understand that mean and sd are more natural descriptors, however I also see a lot of statistical software using L and S. Now that we have a con, is there a pro to this approach? I am trying to justify, or understand why is it so broadly used